# Load images with a specific name

Tags: javascript, html, image

I have a folder with images:

```
image-1-1.jpg
image-2-2.jpg
image-2-3.jpg
image-2-4.jpg
image-2-5.jpg
image-3-1.jpg
image-3-2.jpg
image-3-3.jpg
...
```

but way longer. I also have these links:

```
link 1
link 2
link 3
...
```

I want it so that when a user clicks one of these links the corresponding images will be loaded into my webpage. (Link 1 -> load all images of category 'image-1-something') As you can see the amount of images varies between categories. I've tried this:

```
var img = new Image();
for(var I=1;i<11/*because the maximum amount of images in a category is 10*/;I++){
 img.src = "images/image-"+category+"-"+I+".jpg";
 if(img.width != 0){
  document.getElementById("myDiv").appendChild(img);
 }
```

but the problem with this is that the script checks the width of the image, so if it exists, before the image has completely loaded.

I then tried with the onload event:

```
for(var I=1;i<11;i++){
 img.src = "images/image-"+category+"-"+I+".jpg";
 img.onload = "if(img.width != 0){
  document.getElementById('myDiv').appendChild(img);
 }";
```

but for some reason the onload doesn't seem to work in this loop.

Comment: Onload goes before you give it a src.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok and that is not even a correct code, so here is what you could try:

**EDIT** - Forgot one line

```
for(var i=1;i<11;i++){
 var img = new Image();
 img.onload = function(){ if(this.width != 0){
  document.getElementById('myDiv').appendChild(this);
 }};
 img.src = "images/image-"+category+"-"+i+".jpg";
};
```